# How to copy text from a browser with Java?

Tags: java, browser

Is there a way to copy text from a browser to my Java app ?

For example, at the left side of my screen I open a browser to point to a URL and shows the content of that page, it might be in a frame or CSS or simple html, on the right side of the screen I open a Java Swing application. I'm interested in certain parts of the browser window that shows some text, and I want my Java app [ without me doing anything ] to copy and paste the text into itself, can it be done ?

I know I can use JEditorPane or JTextPane and set it with an HTMLEditorKit, then load the text into the pane, but if the page uses Frames or some other complex ways, the text I get from the Pane is not what I see on the page, so I don't want to do it by loading the URL into my Java app, instead, I wonder if it can be done in the way I mentioned above ?

Comment: How do you know what parts you want to copy?  Are you expecting to see the swing app formatted the same way the browser is? Or you care only about the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following depending on your needs.

With `java.awt.Robot` you can either 1) Take an screenshot if what you neeed is the content ( without the text, just an image of the browser content )    or 2) Move your self into the browser and programatically press: CTRL-A + CTRL-C and return back to your swing app focus and programatically press: CTRL-V ( or CMD or whatever makes sense in your OS )

But again, this might or not work, depending on what you need.

Comment: I don't want to be a dick, but he actually says: "without me doing anything"

Comment: I think he meant "after" the application has launched. Not nothing at all like "coding". Using Robot,  you just sit there and watch it work :)  But, quite frankly is hard to know what the OP really wants.

Comment: This is the closest to what I had in mind, but I wonder if "programatically press: CTRL-A + CTRL-C" in the browser would copy the text, have you tried ?

Comment: I did both in the past ( the image and the text ) ... but neither please me at the end, but I tried for 2 hrs or so, and was for a very naive experiment. It would be great if you put more effor on it, and create something interesting after.. 2 days, who knows.

Comment: @OscarRyz Could you please provide a sample code or tutorial ?

Comment: @KickButtowski Something like this

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking at the problem from the wrong angle. If what you want is to harvest a website, I suggest you have a look at the awesome library [web-harvest](http://web-harvest.sourceforge.net/). With a little Xpath wizardry you can get everything you want.
Doing what you describe would imply inter-process communication that seems like an overkill. There are more ways to download a web-page content than the browser.

Comment: While I agree with you, I think yours is NOT and answer, but a very good comment,  it will fit better on the comments section. :)

Comment: web-harvest works at the HTTP level. you set a URL, it brings you the response. it's up to you to evaluate the JS.

Answer (score 1):

I know a tool but i am not sure it meet your needs. Have you heard about selenium? http://seleniumhq.org/ It can replicate actions taken by the user in a browser and then manipulate them ussing java code. Have a look at the link it may be handy.

Comment: selenium is great for doing quality assurance and automated navigation. not so great to harvest the content of a website.

Comment: You are right, but i just wanted to mention it. I like selenium very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `java.awt.Robot` & a TextField will get the job done, not sure if there is any other way. Have robot press ctrl+a then ctrl+c, bring TextField into focus, and finally have robot press ctrl+v. Now from here you can create a button.setOnAction to save the TextField text into a string. Or you can use a change listener on the TextField setOnKeyReleased to do the same.